# Query get post,how to add comment box

Tags: posts, comments, query

Hello I have a query that gets a post with id=x and it works but it leaves out the comment box.

Is there a way to add "get comment box" to the query?

```
<?php 
$post_id = 104; 
$queried_post = get_post($post_id); 
$content = $queried_post->post_content; 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content); 
echo $content;  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to WPSE!

By default, the comment box does not come with the post object, what you are looking for is the [`comments_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) function.

It should be as simple as changing your code to this:

```
<?php 
$post_id = 104; 
$queried_post = get_post($post_id); 
$content = $queried_post->post_content; 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content); 
echo $content;
comments_template();
?>
```

But if I'm correct this would only work for the current post in the loop.

Looking at the [function in `wp-includes/comment-template.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L849), it uses `global $post` and `global $wp_query` variables. You would need to modify that value in order for the comments template to show up for the post you are displaying.

You could modify that using `query_posts` instead of `get_post`, but be sure to reset the query afterwards:

```
$post_id = 104; 
query_posts( array( 'p' => $post_id ) ); 

while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ); 
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content ); 
    echo $content;

    comments_template();

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata(); // Don't forget!
```

I haven't tested this but it *should* work. I would also suggest reading this awesome [answer by Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/2415) about when to use what function to "get posts". :)

Comment: Hello jared, thanks for the welcome and the code. The 2nd query works but it expresses TWO copies of everything! I have been playing with it but have not suceeded in geting only one copie yet. Thanks Tim

Comment: This what I am using`<?php 
$post_id = 257; 
query_posts( array( 'p' => $post_id ) ); 

while( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ); 
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content ); 
    echo $content;

    comments_template();

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata(); // Don't forget!
?>`

Comment: Works fine, sorry about the confusion I was using it in a tab plugin and it was the tab plugin that was adding the code to all the tabs even the tab the code was in so it was there twice.

Comment: @Tim Glad it works! If my answer was correct can you mark it as the best answer? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

With this query you can add the comments.

```
function get_comments( $args = '' ) {
    $query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    return $query->query( $args );
}
```

Comment: Welcome @clarke.  It's important to format your code as code when posting questions or answers.  Highlight and use the {} button in the editor.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? You posted the [source code of `get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/#source).